# Error while saving ArrayList<String> in saved instance

Tags: android, parcelable, android-savedstate

Actually, I want to save my `LinkedList` in the saved instance so when a user opens the app again he can access the content already stored in the `LinkedList`. I know we need to convert the `LinkedList` into `ArrayList` in order to store it. While saving the `ArrayList` it gives me an error

> wrong 2nd argument type in putParcelableArrayList(). Found '`java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>`', required `java.util.ArrayList<?extends android.os.Parcelable>`.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(FavoriteQuotes);
    savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList("quotes",arrayList);
}
```

I know there are solutions available but it didn't seem to help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do like this

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(FavoriteQuotes);
savedInstanceState.putStringArrayList("key",arrayList );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that exception because `FavoriteQuotes` does not implement the `Parcelable` interface.

Both `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` implement the `Serializable` interface, which means there's a much easier way of persisting your `LinkedList` directly.

Assuming `FavoriteQuotes` is a `LinkedList` of Strings:

```
Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putSerializable("quotes", FavoriteQuotes);
}
```

When you restore it, you will need to call `getSerializable`, and cast it back to its original type:

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    FavoriteQuotes = (LinkedList) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("quotes");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It the above suggestion worked for me. Thanks for the showing me another way to do it. It worked fine.